# What are theories which are not scientific called (such as theories in history)?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Related to [this question/answer](https://www.quora.com/Since-there-will-not-likely-be-any-scientific-fossil-record-linguistic-facts-that-show-us-how-language-specifically-evolved-what-sorts-of-theories-can-we-create-about-this-situation-Is-it-possible-to-create-a/answer/Matthew-McVeagh), if something is not considered a "*scientific* theory", but it is still a theory of how events and evolution might have unfolded, what kind of theory is it?

The example is in trying to reconstruct the evolution of language starting from potentially sign language even as far back as 2 million years ago. You could create all kinds of hypothetical scenarios on how language could have evolved, and present a sequence of logical steps which are logically sound, thus creating a "theory" of how language evolved. But there is not going to be any "fossil evidence" really for it, especially if you are talking specifying the exact order that words evolved in, and over how many years.

To most it seems this would not be considered a **scientific** theory, but instead some other kind of theory. What is it called? Can you reach the same level of rigor as a scientific theory in this context? Perhaps it is called a "computational theory" or "logical theory" or something like that.

Other seemingly related "non-scientific theory" examples would be defining the history of concept evolution in animals, or "theories" on the evolution of consciousness.

Comment: [The scientific theory of evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution); why not? Not "logical theory" for sure...

Comment: Social sciences have theories. For History, I think not, mainly because History is descriptive. But we have hypothesis nevertheless, regarding possible causes of historical facts and similar.

Comment: Yeah but are social science theories called "scientific theories" if there is no fossil evidence?

Comment: "Fossil evidence" is not the only kind of evidence. One can point to analogies and patterns in evolution of other languages, do comparative analysis of contexts where the words are known to be used today, etc. That may not be conclusive, and so it will remain hypothetical but it will be scientific nonetheless. It is how a theory is designed and argued that matters, whether it can be conclusively confirmed or disconfirmed is sometimes a matter of luck. If a theory can be wrong and still scientific it can surely be unconfirmed and still scientific.

Comment: Historical theories, anthropological theories, linguistic theories, music theories... why is this even a question???

Comment: Non-scientists use the word "theory" the way scientists use "hypothesis".  Scientists use the word "theory" the way non-scientists use "fact".  See: Theory of Gravity, Theory of Evolution.  There is no doubt there is gravity or evolution.  These are not possible explanations, rather they're rigorous descriptions.  This seems like a better question for English.SE, you're just asking about definitions.

Comment: @Ryan_L No, scientists do not. They talk of phlogiston and ether theories, which are considered to be false, and string and multiverse theories, which are considered to be hypothetical. The difference between "theory" and "hypothesis" is rather of scope, although it is not strictly observed either. "Hypothesis" is typically applied to narrow claims or classes of phenomena, whereas "theory" is something more broad and comprehensive.

Comment: I want to be able to say "I have a scientific theory of x", because calling something a scientific theory has a lot of _clout_ in todays world. But I need to know clearly what is and what isn't a scientific theory, by understanding more clearly the definitions of various categories of "theories".

Comment: I am afraid you are out of luck. What "scientific theory" means in practice is a theory developed in accordance with standards and practices of an established science. In the past philosophers attempted to come up with a common denominator of such practices, the "scientific method", but sciences turned out to be too diverse for any cogent unifying formulation. It is now believed that there is a variety of different evolving methodologies in different sciences rather than a single "method", but you can read a review of approaches on [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-method/).

Answer (score 2):

The term "scientific theory" is a misnomer, possibly stemming from the defunct but lingering efforts of Analytic Philosophy to rationalize 'science' as a particular thing. A 'theory' is any statement that can undergo rational analysis; 'science' is a *method* of rational analysis applied to such statements, one that can be construed in a number of different ways but which generally seeks to test and support a given statement with empirical referents. Many different fields — including history and the social sciences — use scientific methodologies to analyze the theories they put forth. For instance:

- Historians analyze first-hand writings (letters, accounts, notes, etc), artifacts (materials intentionally or unintentionally left behind) second-hand accounts (people reporting on events they've heard about) to analyze and evaluate theories about historical events
- Anthropologists use immersive experience and in-depth interviews to collect culturaL data that can be used to asses differences and similarities between distinct groups
- Sociologists use statistical analysis to verify claims about regularities within complex human behaviors
- Psychologists create elaborate tests to discover innate tendencies of human individuals

The sticking point for the descendants of the Analytical Philosophy school is a question of objectivity. They seem to reject Durkheim's notion that 'social facts' — regularities in human behavior based in non-physical phenomena like culture, social structure, or psychology — constitute *actual* empirical facts which can be used in analysis. One cannot poke a culture with a stick, so how can one say it really exists? But that objection aside, the only real distinction we find here lies between theories that are analyzed using empirical evidence and theories that are purely philosophical: analyzed through reason alone.